# jQuery animate left flickers on every Browser

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I dont know what am doing wrong with this piece of Code. Its making my Head ache .
When i animate through the images. It flickers like crazy and i dont know why. I am using images with larger dimensions. for an example i am just using low sized ones. I hope someone could help me.

Here is my Code.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/neoragex/27uyv/1/
```

Comment: Zero `flickering` here. Safari, Opera, IE7/8/9, FF, Android tested..

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. Can you please try with images of high dimension? . I have a slow PC. It would be really helpful if you could spare some time :) and help me out :)

Comment: Seems to be fine on my computer with Hi-Res images; however, on a slower Linux box I've got, there is terrible `jumping` and `flickering`. Probably not the most elegant solution for users without power pc's.

Comment: Thank you so much :). Is there anyway to make it work for people who have slower PC's :O ?

Comment: You need a big mouth to take junk food

Comment: Or you need to use your Hands to break em into Small Edible Pieces ^^!~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, all you need is a faster PC with good graphic support and a LATEST browser.

Always keep in mind to deliver LIGHT WEIGHT images to user's browser and give an option to access the High-res image if they want (like a download), else the page will consume much resources.